# What container provider supports org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Using the information provided below can you answer the following questions:

1. What container provider supports org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean so that I may add my application using org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory when creating an end point?
2. What is wrong with the below application that causes `(JAXRSServerFactoryBean)RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(app, JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class);` to throw an illegal argument exception?

---

I am attempting to deploy a JAX-RS application that uses annotations (**no web.xml**) to system that uses a *Java Application Manager* (it is a proprietary system that has ported over some application manager libraries but I am not sure what those are due to little supporting documentation around it).

At a high level I have a Java application that uses JAX-RS annotations, such as ApplicationPath, Path, Produces/Consumes, and JsonProperty, to attempt to create an endpoint on a "application server". I say "application server" because I have no documentation around this system so I am just going to call it that. When attempting to start the application I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No container provider supports the type class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.createEndpoint(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:47)
    at com.app.Server.startServer(Server.java:182)
```

I have researched the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` thrown by the `org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.createEndpoint` function. I am not sure why it would do this because on the cover it appears like the application class is annotated correctly and `extends Application`.

I was able to look at the Server's class code and here is what is being done:

### Server Code

Here a snippet portion of `com.app.Server.startServer(Server.java:182)` code, I cannot alter this code:

```
inside of startServer...

Application app = (Application) Class.forName("com.app.MyApplication").newInstance();

JAXRSServerFactoryBean jaxrsServerFactory = (JAXRSServerFactoryBean)RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(app, JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class);
```

Now my code:

### Application Code

#### MyApplication

```
package com.app;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.app.services.ServiceOne;

@ApplicationPath("base/path")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication() {
        System.out.println(Long.toString(System.nanoTime()) + " " + this.getClass().getName() + " constructor called...");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.ws.rs.core.Application#getClasses()
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        System.out.println(Long.toString(System.nanoTime()) + " " + this.getClass().getName() + " getClasses() method called...");
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(ServiceOne.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

#### My Application's Services

```
package com.app.services.ServiceOne;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// pretend the model imports are here...

@Path("serviceOne")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ServiceOne {

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseObject performService(InputObject body) throws NotFoundException {
        // do whatever to get result and send...
    }

}
```

### Pom.xml Plugins and Dependencies

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

---

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question.

The system I was attempting to deploy my application to already had `jar` files installed on the system in various directories.

I updated my application to include those `jar` files. This was done by updating a descriptor that I use to deploy the application to the system.

Then I and set the `scope` of certain dependencies in my `pom.xml` to `<scope>provided</scope>` so that when the application was packaged by maven, those dependencies would not be included in the final jar.

Below is an example:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.28-RC4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in my side by excluding `jersey-server` which has its own `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate` (see RuntimeDelegate.JAXRS_RUNTIME_DELEGATE_PROPERTY), hence preventing the proper loading of `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RuntimeDelegateImpl`. In my case, jersey-server was brought transitively by `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>XXX</groupId>
        <artifactId>YYY</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```